# Understanding type constraints

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, existential-type

My particular problem may have something to do with existential types but I'm not sure so I won't put it in the title.

Anyways, here's what I'm trying to do.

Have an `Entity` type that wraps over a heterogeneous list of components. Then, I have a `HasComponent a b` typeclass that denotes that the list `b` has a component of the type `a`. Here's how I've written it, and the classes instances.

```
data Entity c = Entity c

data CompNode c n = CompNode c n
data CompEnd = CompEnd

class HasComponent a b where
    getComponent :: b -> a

instance HasComponent a (CompNode a n) where
    getComponent (CompNode a _) = a

instance HasComponent a n => HasComponent a (CompNode b n) where
    getComponent (CompNode _ n) = getComponent n

instance HasComponent a b => HasComponent a (Entity b) where
    getComponent (Entity b) = getComponent b
```

There's also a `HasComponent` instance for `Entity`. That's just for convenience.

So far, everything compiles.

Now, I'd like to try this out. I've made a `DisplayData a` type that holds some data of type `a` that's meant to be displayed. This is one of the components. Then I've made `Displayer a` that is a wrapper around a function of the type `a -> IO ()`. This component is meant to provide a way to show the data.

```
data DisplayData a = DisplayData a
data Displayer a = Displayer (a -> IO ())
```

Now these two components should play nicely together. I wanted to write a function `display` that takes an `Entity` that satisfies some constraints and displays it.

This is my attempt

```
display :: (HasComponent (DisplayData a) c, HasComponent (Displayer a) c) => Entity c -> IO ()
display e = f a
    where Displayer f = getComponent e :: Displayer a
          DisplayData a = getComponent e :: DisplayData a
```

What I would like this to mean is: "If there exists some type a such that `(HasComponent (DisplayData a) c, HasComponent (Displayer a) c)` is true, then `display` can take an `Entity c` and produce an IO action."

What I think this might mean instead is: "If `(HasComponent (DisplayData a) c, HasComponent (Displayer a) c)` is true for any and every type a, then `display` can take an `Entity c` and produce an IO action.

The error I get is this

```
Could not deduce (HasComponent (DisplayData a0) c)
  arising from the ambiguity check for `display'
from the context (HasComponent (DisplayData a) c,
                  HasComponent (Displayer a) c)
  bound by the type signature for
             display :: (HasComponent (DisplayData a) c,
                         HasComponent (Displayer a) c) =>
                        Entity c -> IO ()
  at Components.hs:24:12-94
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
In the ambiguity check for:
  forall c a.
  (HasComponent (DisplayData a) c, HasComponent (Displayer a) c) =>
  Entity c -> IO ()
To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
In the type signature for `display':
  display :: (HasComponent (DisplayData a) c,
              HasComponent (Displayer a) c) =>
             Entity c -> IO ()
```

How do I do what I want here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to reference type variables in the type signature from the body of the function, you need to enable ScopedTypeVariables, and add a forall to the type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

display :: forall a c . (HasComponent (DisplayData a) c, HasComponent (Displayer a) c) 
        => Entity c -> IO ()
display e = f a
    where 
      Displayer f = getComponent e :: Displayer a
      DisplayData a = getComponent e :: DisplayData a
```

But this will still produce an error. The issue is that the type `a` is only mentioned in the context, not the actual type. There will be no way for the compiler to ever instantiate this type. You have several options.

You can add a "dummy" parameter which contains that type:

```
display :: forall a c proxy . 
             (HasComponent (DisplayData a) c, HasComponent (Displayer a) c) 
        => proxy a -> Entity c -> IO ()
display _ e = f a where ...
```

Or, you can add a functional dependency to your class, and some pragmas:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class HasComponent a b | b -> a where
```

which says that the type `a` is determined by the type `b`. In this case, the first form will compile.

Comment: Are there any side-effects of the functional dependency that I should know about?

Comment: The set of instances you can potentially write is smaller. The functional dependency itself doesn't have any other side effects. To make the functional dependency work with your instances, you need UndecidableInstances, which does have the side effect that you can have non-termination in the type checker. For your specific instances, non-termination won't happen.